# WebView returns bad window.innerHeight

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I have an application that makes use of the Android WebView, as well as some JavaScript. When my WebViewClient calls `onPageFinished()`, I alert my JavaScript to run an initializing method. My JavaScript is enabled and loaded before I hit `onPageFinished()`.

In that JavaScript method I make use of `window.innerWidth`. However, the value it returns is always wrong and always the same. Regardless of my orientation it reports that the inner width is 320, and the inner height is 240. (Correct width values for portrait and landscape are 360 and 598 respectively.) Anywhere else I access `window.innerWidth` or `window.innerHeight` in JavaScript it gives me an accurate number.

What is more puzzling is that if I check the height or width of the WebView directly in my `onPageFinished()` call using

`int height = view.getHeight();`

`int width = view.getWidth();`

then it always returns correctly (although it returns the exact pixel numbers, not the DIP). This makes me think that everything has finished loading with the WebView and so I shouldn't have any problems in my JavaScript.

Any ideas as to what is going on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: we have similar issue but get 0 for height and width.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because Javascript executes before WebView's View related initialization. And Android WebView returns a 320x240 default value to JS.
Execute your JS after some time is ok, like this

```
function go() {
int height = view.getHeight();
int width = view.getWidth();
};
window.setTimeout(go, 300);
```

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion. I suppose that could work. I prefer not to add unnecessary time just because I don't understand something. Any idea _why_ the WebView is not ready yet? onPageFinished() has already been called.

Comment: Yes, this is an Android WebKit bug. Actually you need not to wait that long. According to our experiences, we only need to wait 30ms.

Comment: I have the same problem; when a document is loaded into Webview, sometimes the Javascript runs too early and I get window.innerWidth = 320 and window.innerHeight = 240.

I tried the timeout of 100ms but this was not always enough! (Even on a fast device, such as a Nexus 10 tablet!)

Comment: My solution was to check whether window.innerWidth == 320 && window.innerHeight == 240, and in that case wait 100ms and try again.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used the values from `webView.getHeight()` and `webView.getWidth()`, adjusted them for screen density, and passed them in as arguments into a javascript method via `webView.loadUrl()`. This was the only way I could be sure I was getting the right values.

Doing what was suggested in the comments above, checking for the width of 320, and the height of 240 will work great... until you run on a device with those exact dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

After some reading,another solution has occured. in java code, we can use

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable(){ 
    @Override 
    public void run(){
        webview.loadUrl("...")
    }
});
```

add it to QueueMessage,and delayed the js to execute,and it works.

Comment: It has been quite a while, and I am no longer even working on this project, but does that really solve the problem of a race condition? Since the `WebView` runs on its own thread, there is no way to ensure that even a `post()` is enough time to let it initialize, right?

Comment: in the fact, after several trials ,It works. As you said,it is unknown when webview has initialed  !

Comment: as said before,window.setTimeout(go, 300);  it is also unknown.some devices may nedd 1000 !

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

**Java** code in `Activity`:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
```

...

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getWinHeight() {
      return webView.getHeight();
    }
}
```

**JS** code:

```
var winHeight = Android.getWinHeight();
```